# (scheme) how can I use a procedure in a control structure?

Tags: if-statement, scheme, procedure

I have a procedure like

```
(lambda (r) (change table r))
```

I want to use that in an if structure.
My main goal is apply a procedure to list elements which satisfy another procedure.
I can't use filter because I want to see also unchanged element of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (map-if mapper pred lst)
  (map (lambda (x)
         (if (pred x)
             (mapper x)
             x))
       lst))
```